# Playing hd movies in 60fps?

Tags: kubuntu

I'd like to play movies in 60fps. Something i had no trouble with in win8, but i'm wondering if i could achieve the same effect in kubuntu ? 
Here's an example: I have a .mkv movie which is recorded in standard 25fps and i want to make it smoother - to 60fps. I did it in windows using codecs, but kubuntu is quite different and i don't know how (or if this is even possible) to do it. I don't want to convert files - i want it to play it in real-time with 60fps. I haven't tried anything yet, because i don't even know where to start. I tried to look for solution in google, but with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, but here it goes anyways: **XBMC**

This media player does not require manual codec downloads (sort of like VLC), and it can play straight from rar files as well, has many add-ons for online TV / Radio and so on.
It has many features to fine-tune playback: http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Settings/Videos

Give it a try and see if it works for you. Make sure you install it from the official PPA sources.

```
   sudo apt-get install python-software-properties pkg-config
   sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install xbmc
```